# Finding the C Wire for the LH33WP003A Control Board and Ecobee Premuim

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I am installing a new Ecobee Smart Thermostat. My old thermostat didn't use the C-Wire. However, when I pulled the cable out of the wall their is a blue wire. I hooked it to the Ecobee but it didn't power up. I figured it wasn't hooked up on the furnace control board.

My furnace is a Bryant Model 582ANW024060aaad. It's an outdoor unit with Ac/heat. I know the common wire is usually blue but mine seems to be brown. On my control board (LH33WP003A) what I believe to be "C" has a brown cable running to the 24V box above it. It splits off and has a wire nut on it but it's not connected with any other cables. The cables next to the brown cable run from my inside my house to the thermostat.

The following cables are connected by a wire nut (see images)
Blue & Yellow -
Green & Green -
Red & Red -
Black & White -
Brown

Should I hook up the brown cable to the yellow and blue cables with a wire nut?
Will this give me power for my thermostat? I included a link to the PDF of the control board schematics.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Control Board LH33WP003A]

[image: C-Wire Slot?]

[image: 24V Box]

[image: Thermostat Cables From House]

[image: Brown Wire]

[image: Thermostat Cables]

[image: Cables Blue and Yellow]

[Control Board Schematics](http://www.patriot-supply.com/files/ICM291.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

This is your "C" wire:

[image: C WIRE]

Comment: Just because it's labeled "common"? ;)

Comment: Mainly because it's labelled "C" on the PL2 connector.

Comment: Yeah, or that one...

Comment: Thank you. So my Brown wire is the common wire. I'm assuming that's what BRN stands for

Comment: Don't rely on the colors, rely on the terminal that the wire is hooked to.